# How to find an update the value of a cell based on row data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 10 |
| 10 | 15 |
| 5 | 20 |

This is a sample table, here we can see that there 2 `ID` as `5`, here if there are more than 1 same ID (like here there are 2 similar ID (`5`)) I want to combine the two rows so that new `Value` = Sum of `Value` with similar ID and delete the old `ID` and `Value`

So expected new table is

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 15 |
| 5 | 30 `(10+20)` |

Any way of doing this will suffice:

- directly in the spreadsheet
- via the Sheets API

Comment: what about if you use a query?

Answer (score 0):

You can Pretty much have 2 tables, one where the data is and the other one where you will show the results. For example, the first table with the data:

[image: Table with the data]

Then the 2nd table with the results. For this I used the following formula:

```
=query(A2:B,"Select A, Sum(B) where A is not null group by A")
```

[image: Table with results]

You will be reading the data from table 1 and just show the results on the 2nd one.